# How to save score

Tags: android

I'm making an Android quiz. I used SQLite for storing the questions and answers. It has 3 difficulties: easy, medium, and hard. I need help in storing the score user got in each difficulty. I want to store the score in another activity called scores like `Easy 5/5 Medium 5/5 Hard 5/5`.

Here's my Database:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QUIZ";
    private static final String TABLE_QUIZ = "quiz";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta";
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb";
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc";
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd";
    private static final String q_level = "level";
    private static final String QuestionNumber = "q_number";
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public String question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, answer;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUIZ + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD  +" TEXT, " + q_level + " TEXT, " + QuestionNumber + " INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q2','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q3','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q4','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q5','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','5')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','5')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','5')");
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }

    private void addQuestions() { }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUIZ);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void getQuestByLevel(String level, int qnum) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ +  " WHERE "+ q_level +"  = '"+ level +"' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                question=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUES));
                optionA=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTA));
                optionB=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTB));
                optionC=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTC));
                optionD=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTD));
                answer=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Quiz Activity:

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    int score = 0;
    int qnum = 1;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
    Button butNext;
    RadioGroup rdgrp;

    String corAnswer = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        rdgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rdd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        corAnswer = "";
        onCreateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onCreateQuestion() {
        String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

        txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
        rda.setText(db.optionA);
        rdb.setText(db.optionB);
        rdc.setText(db.optionC);
        rdd.setText(db.optionD);
        corAnswer = db.answer;

        qnum++;
    }

    public void onClickNext(View view) {
        String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

        RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
        RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if (answer == null) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "select an answer please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (corAnswer!= null && corAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase((String) answer.getText())) {
            score++;
            Log.d("answer", "Your score" + score);
        }
        if (qnum <= 5) {

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
        rda.setText(db.optionA);
        rdb.setText(db.optionB);
        rdc.setText(db.optionC);
        rdd.setText(db.optionD);
        corAnswer = db.answer;
        qnum++;
        rdgrp.clearCheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: in the codes given there is no problem. I just need help in how to save the score the user got in the quiz per difficulty

Comment: create different table for each difficulty

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite Database`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table (**Score Table**) in you SQLite Database where you can store the score of the user by each quiz, and use that table to fetch the result that you want to show in another activity.

You can use the following snipe to define the **Score Table**:

```
private static final String TABLE_SCORE= "score";     
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUIZ_ID + "INTEGER, " + SCORE + " INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: uhm im having trouble calling the score of each difficulty can u help me on how to call it ?